# How can I select a selected item from one array from another? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, select, selecteditem

Please help, I don't understand how I can select a selected item if it comes from somewhere else and is in a different array. If this is not possible, is it possible to search for an item in the current array and select it as a select item if yes, can you give me an example please.
PS:
I was able to set an item if I selected it as the original from an existing item like this, but would like to select it from a different array

```
$scope.initialMention = [             
              $scope.mentions[0][0],
              $scope.mentions[1][0]
];
```

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.mentions = [
          [
              {
                  "name": "developer@medallia.com",
                  "uuid": "31a52cab-429d-4efa-91dc-d79b154dd4f9",
                  "type": "Users",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "developer2@medallia.com",
                  "uuid": "020e5b7c-98b6-457a-a90e-d78253eef11d",
                  "type": "Users",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "testTeam ",
                  "uuid": "fe5b143c-c6c2-4d34-a152-2a679899541d",
                  "type": "Teams",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "41335412351235 ",
                  "uuid": "d751eb81-7363-4f32-a91c-dc6c69d1c113",
                  "type": "Teams",
                  "selected": false,
              }
          ],
          [
              {
                  "name": "developer@medallia.com",
                  "uuid": "31a52cab-429d-4efa-91dc-d79b154dd4f9",
                  "type": "Users",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "developer2@medallia.com",
                  "uuid": "020e5b7c-98b6-457a-a90e-d78253eef11d",
                  "type": "Users",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "testTeam ",
                  "uuid": "fe5b143c-c6c2-4d34-a152-2a679899541d",
                  "type": "Teams",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "41335412351235 ",
                  "uuid": "d751eb81-7363-4f32-a91c-dc6c69d1c113",
                  "type": "Teams",
                  "selected": false,
              }
          ]
      ]

      $scope.initialMention = [             
              {
                  "name": "testTeam ",
                  "uuid": "fe5b143c-c6c2-4d34-a152-2a679899541d",
                  "type": "Teams",
                  "selected": false,
              },
              {
                  "name": "41335412351235 ",
                  "uuid": "d751eb81-7363-4f32-a91c-dc6c69d1c113",
                  "type": "Teams",
                  "selected": false,
              }
    ];
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

<br />
<br />
<br />
<div ng-repeat="mention in mentions">
    <select 
      ng-model="initialMention[$index]"
      ng-options="item as item.name for item in mention">
    </select>
    <br />
    {{ initialMention[$index]}}
    <br />
    {{mention[$index]}}
 </div>


  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: i fixed it in this way - https://plnkr.co/edit/C0C4aylYtmXAXFNX, if somebody could recommend something better, i will be grateful

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.initialMention = $scope.mentions.flat().slice(0,2)
```